# net/ldap returns Ldaperror 34 , invalid dn syntax in Rails with devise and devise_ldap, dn should be correct

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ldap

I'm trying to implement authentication ( simple "is he one of us" ) for a ruby on rails app using net/ldap, devise and devise_ldap_authenticatable.

When I try to log in the error message down below pops up, when I go to the console and try ldap.bind with the same username/password combination it returns false, but a ldap.open do |ldap| ; ldap.search (...) ; end returns the search successfully. Also an anonymous bind returns true,so the issue must be with the DN. However the DN should be correct. Through print statement debugging I found out that the exact input I give ( which SHOULD be correct ) is passed through the gems to the ldap server. I'm running out of ideas, any thought?

```
LDAP: Authorizing user uid=name,ou=People,dc=test,dc=com
LDAP: LDAP search: uid=name
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 89ms
Net::LDAP::LdapError (Invalid binding information):
net-ldap (0.3.1) lib/net/ldap.rb:1230:in `bind_simple'
net-ldap (0.3.1) lib/net/ldap.rb:1209:in `bind'
net-ldap (0.3.1) lib/net/ldap.rb:718:in `bind'
devise_ldap_authenticatable (0.4.4) lib/devise_ldap_authenticatable
/ldap_adapter.rb:134:in `admin'
devise_ldap_authenticatable (0.4.4) lib/devise_ldap_authenticatable
/ldap_adapter.rb:107:in `has_required_attribute?'
devise_ldap_authenticatable (0.4.4) lib/devise_ldap_authenticatable
/ldap_adapter.rb:77:in `authorized?'
devise_ldap_authenticatable (0.4.4) lib/devise_ldap_authenticatable
/ldap_adapter.rb:14:in `valid_credentials?'
devise_ldap_authenticatable (0.4.4) lib/devise_ldap_authenticatable/model.rb:38:in `valid_ldap_authentication?'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/core_ext/object/try.rb:32:in `try'
devise_ldap_authenticatable (0.4.4) lib/devise_ldap_authenticatable/model.rb:65:in 
authenticate_with_ldap'
devise_ldap_authenticatable (0.4.4) lib/devise_ldap_authenticatable/strategy.rb:16:in
authenticate!'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/strategies/base.rb:53:in `_run!'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/proxy.rb:354:in `block in _run_strategies_for'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/proxy.rb:349:in `each'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/proxy.rb:349:in `_run_strategies_for'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/proxy.rb:319:in `_perform_authentication'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/proxy.rb:127:in `authenticate!'
devise (2.1.2) app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:15:in `create'
```

Comment: Can you post the ldap config for devise?

Answer (score 0):

With any of these types of problems, try using a known good tool like `ldapsearch` to determine if the distinguished name, credentials, base object, and so forth are correct.

#### see also

- [LDAP: using ldapsearch](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/mastering-ldapsearch/)